# If $M$ is a complete Riemannian manifold, then $M$ is not extendible

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I am trying understand the proof of the propostion $3$ of [this](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Elee/Sven05.pdf) lecture notes, but I have a doubt: why $\gamma$ is not defined for some $t \leq 1$, but it is defined for $t$ small enough? I thought $\gamma$ was defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ once that it is only a reparametrization of $\psi$ and $M$ is complete.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $M$ is a proper open subset of $M'$, the point $p \in \partial M$ is not in $M$. The curve $\gamma(t) = \psi(1-t)$ is in $M$ for all small enough $t$, and it's also geodesic in $M$. Since $\gamma$ is geodesic in $M$ and $M$ is complete, $\gamma(t)$ is defined *and in $M$* for all $t\in\mathbb R$. This contradicts $\gamma(1) = \psi(0) = p \not\in M$.

I guess that they wrote "for some $t \leq 1$" instead of "exactly at $t = 1$" since it could be the case that $\gamma$ hits the point $p$ before $t = 1$ (say, if $\psi$ were to loop around and hit its starting point $p$ twice before reaching $q$).

Comment: I agree with you when you stated "when it hits $p$, it would leave $M$", but this occurs for $t = 1$ because $\gamma(0) = \psi(1) = p \in \partial M \subset M' \backslash M$, so why $\gamma$ was not defined for "some $t \leq 1$" instead of "exactly in $t = 1$"? Is it can be not defined for $t < 1$? Another question: what is the relation of the proposition that you quoted with my question? If $\gamma$ was geodesic in $M$, then it would be geodesic in $M'$, I can not see a contradiction in this. I think your argument could finish when you stated "when it hits $p$, it would leave $M$"

Comment: You are right, the argument could be finished at that point. Indeed, completeness of $M$ ensures that the curve $\gamma(t)$, which is a geodesic in $M$, ought to be defined and *in $M$* for all $t$. I apologize if I've caused any confusion; I'll update my answer shortly.